# why do I need to put a return statement right before a function ends?

Tags: javascript, function, return

```
function getPizzaCost(size, nTopping) {
  let cost = 10; // base cost for a small pizza
  if(size === "medium") {cost += 4;}
  else if(size === "large") {cost += 8;}
  cost += nTopping;
}

let pizzaSize = "medium";
let numToppings = 19;

let cost = getPizzaCost(pizzaSize, numToppings);
console.log("cost " + cost + "$")
```

I know I'm supposed to put a return cost right below the cost += nToppings but why do I need to do that? is there a specific reason for that? I've search up why we needed it but it got a little confusing

Comment: Inside the function you could use multiple variables. How should the compiler/interpreter know which one you want to have exported?

Comment: What is it that you find confusing about needing a `return` statement?

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript

Comment: because without `return` you'll get `undefined`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `cost` is a local variable to that function and the value of it is not accessible from outside. So the return statements gives back the value of `cost` once the function is executed.

You can also declare it outside and use that , but that variable will be avaialble to be used by other function which will give an erroneous result.

Answer (score 0):

A function without return keyword, it will automatically return undefined.

Why do you need to return cost?

```js
function getPizzaCost(size, nTopping) {
  let cost = 10; // base cost for a small pizza
  const randomVar = "random"
  if(size === "medium") {cost += 4;}
  else if(size === "large") {cost += 8;}
  cost += nTopping;
}
```

In the function above how does js know what variable it need to return, so, if you want get `cost` variable value you need to `return cost`.